# WebAPI vs WCFService for receiving files plus strings

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I've read a lot recently which suggests that WCF may not have a long-term future, or at least, this is very much unknown, as WebAPI is becoming the tool of choice.

I need to create a WebAPI/WCF Service that receives three pieces of information:

1. An XML file (which may be large, up to 10mb)
2. A username string
3. A password string

The service will be hosted on IIS as part of a ASP.NET4.5 web forms site, but will receive data mainly sent from ERP systems such as Oracle.  Therefore it will be HTTP-based by default.

Based on the first statement, could anyone give me a clue as to which approach I should take? I am mainly focused on reliability and ease of crafting the Request from the client.

WCF Services appear the best choice to me because of the service contract approach, but I'm not very clued up on WebAPI's strengths.

I don't mean this to be a drawn out discussion, but short and factual given that a lot of people must be thinking the same thing.

Comment: _"I've read a lot recently which suggests that WCF [...] future [...] unknown, as WebAPI is becoming the tool of choice."_ - can you show me where such things are being said? :-) It sounds like rumors from people who don't know what they're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made better results with simpler frameworks such as WebAPI or ServiceStack.

Even if the contract based approach is easy to implement, you will find several limitations, it is not so clean like WebAPI and not so easy to maintain.

With WebAPI you are free to define your API in a more HTTP similar approach, and if you like REST, WebAPI is the right option.

I would take WCF only in the case that you have to implement a SOAP WS.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea about the future of WCF is wrong. There is a difference between WCF and WebAPI.
WebAPI is basically the RESTfull service/ WCF REST.
There is huge difference between REST and WCF : you can google for more details.
The choice of which one to use actually depends on what you need.
You should not provide highly confedential data using REST. Use WCF for this purpose.
And also if you need to provide your customers with let's say the list of the data which will be pretty much the same for all/many of your customers, it's better to use REST because it uses caching and will reduce the load on your database and the servers.

Comment: Thanks. I'm glad that people here disagree with what I read elsewhere.  That's reassuring.  Surely both WCF or REST are okay for confidential data if transferring data over SSL?